# App not showing in Google Play Store

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services

I just uploaded my app to Android Play store.  The problem now is when I search it at google play store, other app with similar name will pop on top of my app and I need to keep scroling until i found my app.

My I know why will this happen?  Is it because of My app is a new app so need wait more download and review? or I have to implement "App indexing" "I search from google" to allow user to search my app easily on google play store?

Comment: How long ago did you upload it? It may take up to several hours, maybe even a full day, until you can search and find it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Google wont push your app to the top until you've had more reviews and downloads than your competitors. There are a few things you can do to try and improve your position.

1. Try get a more unique name for your App.
2. Get as many friends and family members you can to download and review your app.
3. Use the name a few times in the description of your app.
4. Improve the text in your app description and info sections on the listing.
5. Give it some time.

Answer (score 1):

App positioning in Goolge play store is a fine art, indeed there are many factors that can improve your apps position in the list.  Below are a number of ways to improve your listing:

- A full and comprehensive store listing
- Regular and frequent application updates also promote your listing
- SEO best practices
- Rating and reviews always help too!

Answer (score 0):

There're **two possibilities**.

1. One big posibility, the name for your app has keywords which are very competitive in play store. You need first to do some app search optimization.
2. There’s the second possibility that the app that you’re trying to search for is not compatible with your device. That is why it is not showing up in your device..

However, when you look upon the desktop site, it is visible.

Also, remember that It takes a while to appear on the play store and get ranked in search if you just uploaded it. Apart from that, you may also have poor search ranking if people tend to uninstall it, or you may not be searching for the right term.

> You can rank good with these tips

1. Give it some time and perform **ASO (APP Store Optimization)**
2. Promote your application across different platforms like **Blogs, youtube, Facebook pages.**
3. Use ad services like google ads or Facebook ads to gain organic users.

I published an application with a unique name "[Home Workout without Equipment](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.homeworkoutapp.noequipmentworkout)" one month back and It's ranked with the help of ASO and proper keywords. It has 1000+ reviews and 50,000+ downloads in a short period of time.

So remember….

(Formula for my success)

[[ASO + App Markeetring + Reviews = App Ranking](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.tulip.weather)][2](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.tulip.weather)

ASO+ AM+ R = AR

Play store rank apps on top based on good ASO and deep links associated with apps along with downloads and reviews. (Always remember to gain organic users)